# Cannot logon to iCloud.com - stuck on verify email dialog

Tags: icloud, apple-id

Today when i logon to icloud.com I get asked to verify my email. I have never got that question before. And when I fill in the email, it says "You cannot configure an apple-ID with this email address - try with a different one". This is my primary email, and it has worked before. I even tried with both @me and @icloud.com but it will not accept any of them.

Comment: This is something you need to contact Apple Support about. If you’re having account issues, only Apple can assist.

Comment: Thank you. Probably. As a temporary workaround I logged in using my iphone and fingerprint to the Apple ID webpage. I then switched from .me to .icloud for my apple-id - and now I could log on using my iMac. I got an error message when switching back, but probably there is a time limit set. I will try to switch back to .me later on.

Answer (score 1):

I spoke with Apple Support. They did not see any obvious reason for initially not beeing able to log on to iCloud. I told about my workaround to use iPhone to login, and changing the ID from @me.com to @icloud.com.

They were not able to help me switch back from @icloud to @me as my primary id. It might be because some days between changes are needed. They said I could still logon both with the primary and secondary id, and that it did not have any major consequences. So we closed the issue without further investigation. Now, several months later I tried to change back to @me.com as my primary id for curiosity. First I got an error message, but then it worked on the second try. Next time I will probably call Apple Support first thing, without experimenting too much with this ID.